# How to divide a name into rows in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want a name to be passed as a parameter to a stored procedure and when i execute this stored procedure, it should divide the name into rows.
For example if pass 'Peter', output should be

P 
e 
t 
e 
r

Comment: I thought a way to find length of parameter passed then print individual character of name, but how to do that

Comment: Join to a Tally and use `CHARINDEX` to get each character.

Comment: See https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1 @Larnu `SUBSTRING` not `CHARINDEX`

Comment: Yep, @Charlieface , coffee clearly hasn't kicked in yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```
> declare @input varchar(max);
> set @input = 'Peter'
>
> declare @table TABLE (char varchar(1));
>
>
> while (LEN(@input)> 0)
> begin
> insert into @table select substring(@input,1,1)
> select @input = RIGHT(@input,Len(@input)-1) 
> end
>
> select * from @table
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | char |
> | :--- |
> | P    |
> | e    |
> | t    |
> | e    |
> | r    |
> ```

> ```
> declare @T table
> (
>   ID int identity,
>   names varchar(10)
> )
>
> insert into @T
> select 'Peter' 
>
> ;with cte as 
> (
>   select ID,
>          left(names, 1) as Data,
>          stuff(names, 1, 1, '') as remains
>   from @T
>   where len(names) > 0
>   union all
>   select ID,
>          left(remains, 1) as Data,
>          stuff(remains, 1, 1, '') as remains
>   from cte
>   where len(remains) > 0
> )
> select ID,
>        Data
> from cte
> order by ID
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Data
> -: | :---
>  1 | P   
>  1 | e   
>  1 | t   
>  1 | e   
>  1 | r
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a70ad360fa411fb23eb57034bd46824)*

Comment: A `WHILE` would be, by far, the slowest way to do this.

Comment: @Larnu as the OP didn't detail his answer I may be use CTE instead of a WHILE

Answer (score 3):

The fastest method to do this would be with a Tally and `SUBSTRING`. I *assume* that the name won't be longer than 100 characters, and that (as it's a name) it's an `nvarchar` rather than a `varchar`. You can then do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Name nvarchar(100) = N'Peter';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATALENGTH(@Name) / 2) --If a varchar, remove the / 2
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name,T.I,1) AS C
FROM Tally T;
```